# Are Actionscript integers Numbers in the debugger?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've stumbled upon a strange thing in Flex. I created an integer variable:

```
var foo:int = 1;
```

And in the debugger it says foo is a **Number** with a value of 1.

It wasn't a biggie for me but seems Numbers are being sent instead of integers when doing remote service calls. What's happening here?

Comment: I don´t know why that is, but is this really a problem? You will never send anything but a int anyway meaning there will never be any decimals.

Comment: Maybe this is not a huge problem, but at a certain project it is for me. I'm sending parameters in AMF to the AMF Zend server. Because of this type thing I don't know if the param was an int or a float. I can convert it anyway, that's not a problem, but I'm really interested why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the output tries to be as primitive as possible - here's an intriguing example:

```
var i:int = 1;
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

trace(typeof(i)); // number
trace(typeof(mc)); // object
```

Did a bit of reasearch: typeof can only return of of these six results:

```
Array -> object
Boolean -> boolean
Function -> function
int -> number
Number -> number
Object -> object
String -> string
uint -> number
XML -> xml
XMLList -> xml
```

> "Evaluates expression and returns a
>   string specifying the expression's
>   data type. The result is limited to
>   six possible string values: boolean,
>   function, number, object, string, and
>   xml. If you apply this operator to an
>   instance of a user-defined class, the
>   result is the string object. The
>   typeof operator is included for
>   backward compatibility. Use the is
>   operator to check type compatibility."

Answer (score -1):

I have found an interesting post about int vs Number: [Avoid ints in ActionScript](http://kuwamoto.org/2006/06/15/avoid-ints-in-actionscript/). Given that and that int is also an object: [ActionScript Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html) what happens is that the debugger will convert int into Number and display its value perhaps just because Number is a broader type and can hold all ints while the other way round is not true.

Comment: I'd caution you that the linked article is almost 6 years old.  Things have changed a lot in that time regarding best practices on when to use what datatypes.  Also, Number is an object as well if you read the docs.  All the prims are also objects.

Comment: I would urge you to read before you accuse: I said "i found an interesting post" which doesn't mean "this is my definite answer", I said "int is also an object" which doesn't mean "number is not an object", on the contrary, it suggests that number is an object. I still think my post can help even if it doesn't give a solution and your comment is pretty contraproductiv.

Comment: No accusations here, and certainly I'm not the one who downvoted.